# Bind object to scollevent and scroll with up and down movement

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

So I have tried to achieve the following affect:

imagine you have a long list with items and a header that is constantly visible to you when you scroll through the list. This header just takes up space. Some apps handle it with the header only being visible, when the user scrolls back up. When the user scroll down the header just moves itself out of the view. I was close with getting this effect done:

```
 private void listview_allAds_Scrolled(object sender, ScrolledEventArgs e)
        {
            double heightOfScrollView = scrollview_header.Height;
           
            if (e.ScrollY < oldValue)
            {
                isScrollingUp = true;
                oldValue = e.ScrollY;
            }
            else
            {
                isScrollingUp = false;
                oldValue = e.ScrollY;
            }
           
            if (isScrollingUp)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Up");
           
                if (!isHeaderBack)
                {
                    if (scrollview_header.TranslationY <= 0)
                    {
                        scrollview_header.TranslationY = -e.ScrollY - scrollview_header.TranslationY;
                        isHeaderBack = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        isHeaderBack = true;
                        scrollview_header.TranslationY = 0;
                        //stop
                    }
                }
                               
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Down");
           
                if (e.ScrollY <= heightOfScrollView)
                {
                    scrollview_header.TranslationY = -e.ScrollY;
                    isHeaderBack = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    isHeaderBack = false;
                    // stop
                }
            }
        }
```

So, I have two elements a `ListView` that is calling this function whenever it is scrolled and a header `scrollview_header`.

But the result seems glitchy:

https://im5.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-5-144e3fbffbaa.gif

You see, the header is bugging out a bit, but only on the part where i scroll up again.

Can you fix this issue? it is probably my math...

Comment: Please avoid putting tags in title when it is not necessary [Should I use tags in titles?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Answer (score 0):

If the header View is a `StackLayout` as follows:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="35" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackLayout x:Name="stackLayout"
                 Grid.Row="0">
        ...
    </StackLayout>
    <ListView x:Name="listView"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
              Grid.Row="1">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            ...
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Xamarin.Forms `ListView` provides an `OnItemAppearing` event you can subscribe to. With this you can track your scroll direction by finding the index of the item that appeared and comparing it to the last item that appeared. Try something like this:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyItemType> Items { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<MyItemType>();
    int lastItemIndex;
    int currentItemIndex;

    public MainPage()
    {
        ...
        listView.ItemAppearing += ListView_ItemAppearing;
    }

    async void ListView_ItemAppearing(object sender, ItemVisibilityEventArgs e)
    {
        MyItemType item = e.Item as MyItemType;

        currentItemIndex = Items.IndexOf(item);
        if (currentItemIndex > lastItemIndex)
        {
            await stackLayout.FadeTo(0, 1000);
            stackLayout.IsVisible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            stackLayout.IsVisible = true;
            await stackLayout.FadeTo(1, 1000);
        }
        lastItemIndex = currentItemIndex;
    }
}
```

**Note**: Flickering is really due to `ListView` being resized when the `StackLayout` shows and hides, so make sure that the `ListView` is not getting resized. Perhaps put the `ListView` and the `StackLayout` in a grid so that when you show and hide the `StackLayout` the `ListView` does not get resized

Comment: Well that will just hide the view without animating it, thats not what i was hoping for

Comment: @Jay Okey, you could add [Fading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/animation/simple#fading) animation to check whether is your wants. I have updated the answer.

Comment: yeah sure, but id like for it to be moved up with the speed of the scroll, that is why i am doing this inside OnScroll

Comment: @Jay Okey, I found that your shared gif link was broken, could you update it with a valid one. Then I will re-check that.